# Long running chkdsk on Windows 7 1TB external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

We had a lightning storm and power fluctuated. External hard drive lost some files.  I thought I could run a chkdsk on the drive.  It has been running over a week.  I checked box, "Automatically fix file system errors". As of this moment it shows 56395 files records processed.  The progress bar is completely blank, as it was at the beginning.  How much longer will it run, or is it doing anything?  I have read that you don't want to stop chkdsk once it begins.

Comment: running over a week is quite long. I guess your hard drive is damaged or bad which cause it can read and make make no progress on chkdsk

Comment: I would cancel the `chkdsk` and run a hard drive test for bad sectors. While `chkdsk` does this, you might get better results using a boot disk tool from the HDD manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

In the situation as described, taking way longer than it should, the user has to make a judgement call, and bail out of the situation, even if that means booting, or hard stopping the computer.

I have seen checkdisk fails where the work is mostly complete, but the program will not end, and even situations where the long running checkdisk was hurting more than helping.

In the situation you describe right here, I will call it for you, its dead :-) Being an external drive, you could try the "safe removal" first, but it may hang up also.
 Then reboot, check the integrity of your data now, which includes actually playing or viewing the files, not just looking at the file structure.  If everything looks ok, then back it up, and run the chkdsk again  to finish.

. . . you do have a backup? :-)

Comment: It is my backup.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I cancelled the check disk, and will see what I find from here.

Comment: IF it's your backup, then get a new disk and redo your backup.  If the drive isn't completely worthless then it can be relegated to light duty.

Comment: @afrazier's comment makes it sound like the disk is physically bad.  It may be; it also could just be that the filesystem layout got written incorrectly as a result of an incomplete task because of the power failure.  In that case, formatting the disk would result in perfectly working, usable hardware (after deleting all of the contents once).

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows Event Log and see if there are disk errors, particularly "operation was retried". Open Computer Management (run compmgmt.msc) and in the left pane, nav to System Tools | Event Viewer | Windows Logs , click System. In the right pane, click Filter Current Log. In the Event Sources selector, select "disk" and "Disk". OK. Your middle pane should now show all disk-related events.

If there aren't any "warning" or "error" level, you're good. :) You may be good even if there are a few, depending on what they are.

If the text shows anything about "retries", though, that's bad. Retries should be extremely uncommon, like maybe one a day per drive that's being read and written continuously.  If you see flurries of retries from your external drive, just scrap it. Especially since it is only your backup, you have nothing to lose by this.